# How do I remove the mesh of the starter character?

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

```
local startPlr = game:GetService("StarterPlayer")


script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    startPlr.StarterCharacter.ear:Destroy()
end)
```

I'm trying to remove the mesh called ear of StarterPlayer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you tested it? If you change the default character after you joined, I assume it won't affect you anymore.